# Identify database objects having DBLINK

Tags: oracle, plsql, dblink

After refreshing a local database with PROD database, we are getting some invalid objects in local database. 
After analysis, we found that those objects are invalid because of DBLINK which are not there in local database, but those invalid objects are not appearing in DBA_ERRORS table.

Once we compile the local object, which we did through DBA's, the objects appears in DBA_ERRORS table. But we don't have privileges to compile those objects. So we need to identify those objects without individual compilation.

Is there any SQL query by which we can identify which OBJECT is invalid because of which DBLINK.
We have used DBA_DEPENDENCIES table, but it is not giving correct result.
Query used:

```
 select * from dba_dependencies where referenced_link_name is not null
```

Comment: Are you able to run that query (or ask for it to be run) in the production environment? You get no output in your local DB because only objects that exist are included, and the missing links don't exist at all here. (Otherwise you'll have to search `dba_source`, starting with looking for @. You could limit that to things that are invalid in `dba_objects`.)

Comment: In PROD environment, we have DBLINKS available, so the objects are not failing there. The issue is, when we import objects, they become invalid, but the errors are not appearing in DBA_ERRORS table. We have a utility, which prints error message from DBA_ERRORS table. So in this case, how can we get the errors for the object.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. If you query `dba_dependencies` in the production environment, that will tell you what is missing from the local environment. They will show up there. (There won't be errors, but there will be dependencies listed).

Comment: my issue is related with local database. Somehow i need to find the error in local environment, without compiling. Is there any way to get that.

Comment: If you can identify the invalid objects, if you try to call any proc/func in each of those, they will automatically compile; the errors will then appear in `dba_errors`. Looking at the dependencies in production will tell you which links are used by each invalid object though, which might save you some time. Depends if you plan to create dummy links, or modify the code to remove the link references.